# SELECT … WHERE Query in DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have a SQL query:

```
select
    DISTINCT [doc]
from
    [table] 
where [doc] like 'DS%'
```

I want to rewrite it with DAX, but it isn’t working. Here is what I have now:

```
= 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'table'[doc] ),
    SEARCH("DS", DISTINCT('table'[doc]),1,0) > 0
)
```

How would I create a similar query with DAX?

Comment: I want to output the count rows in measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL predicate that is used here translates to `starts with ds`.

Example

```
declare @t1 as table (doc varchar(max))
insert into @t1
select * from (values('ds1'),('ds2'),('nods'),('no ds'),('nothing')) t(a)

select * from @t1

select distinct(doc) from
@t1
where 
doc like 'ds%'
```

[image: s1]

The exact DAX equivalent Measure would be

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[doc] ),
    FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Table'[doc] ), LEFT ( 'Table'[doc], 2 ) = "ds" )
)
```

[image: s2]

Internally `FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Table'[doc] ), LEFT ( 'Table'[doc], 2 ) = "ds" )` returns a table like this

[image: s3]